# Combobox display format with 2 data values

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

In my extjs combobox, i'd like to display 2 values that i have with a format such as

eg. value1 - value2

if value2 does not exists, i'd like it to display just value1 without the dash

eg. value1

```
var combo = new Ext.form.field.ComboBox({
    // ...
    getInnerTpl : function() { 
         if ('{value2}' == null || '{value2}' == '') { // doesnt work..
            return '{value1}';
         } else {
            return '{value1} - {value2}';
         } 
     },
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the [`displayTpl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.4/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-displayTpl):

> The template to be used to display selected records inside the text
>   field. An array of the selected records' data will be passed to the
>   template.

For example:

```
displayTpl: [
    '<tpl for=".">',
    '{value1}{[values.value1 && values.value2 ? \' - \' : \'\']}{value2}',
    '<tpl if="xindex < xcount">,</tpl>',
    '</tpl>'
]
```

---

You can change [`itemTpl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.4/#!/api/Ext.view.AbstractView-cfg-itemTpl) of the bound list using the [`listConfig`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.4/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-listConfig):

> The inner portion of the item template to be rendered. Follows an
>   XTemplate structure and will be placed inside of a tpl.

For example:

```
listConfig: {
    itemTpl: '{value1}{[values.value1 && values.value2 ? \' - \' : \'\']}{value2}'
}
```

---

**A working example:** https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/v32

Comment: looks like this doesnt work as my app is using extjs 4.2. unfortunately, i would not be able to upgrade.... is there a way to get this to work using extjs 4.2?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like changing the displayTpl to the following worked based on @CD.. answer for extjs 4.2

```
displayTpl: new Ext.XTemplate( '<tpl for=".">',
    '{value1}{[values.value1 && values.value2 ? \' - \' : \'\']}{value2}',
    '<tpl if="xindex < xcount">,</tpl>',
    '</tpl>')
```